# How to get Current Currency SIGN in UI component field

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, placeholder

I have created a Custom Module using the UI Component on Admin Side. Now i Need to show a Current Currency Sign in this field.

SS:

[image]

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: Please add <dataType>pirce</dataType> in UI component field

Comment: @Abdul it is not working. I have used this in my form.